# Update symfony 2 version / composer.lock

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to upgrade symfony to 2.6.

Right now it is version 2.4.

When i change my composer.json to :

```
"symfony/symfony": "~2.6",
```

and then run the :

```
composer:update
```

It doesn't do anything. 
I have a composer.lock inside my project.
How can i ignore this file and update my symfony2 project to a newer version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command is

```
composer update
```

or, if you don't have `composer` installed globally,

```
php composer.phar update
```

You should also change ***_branch_-alias***:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "_branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
    }
}
```